# Selenium on Twitter for user information: no such elements

Tags: python, selenium

I try to use Selenium to get specific users' information (e.g., num of followers) by entering their page using ids. The thing is, though I find the needed information in the INSPECT, I cannot position it using Selenium, even with the help of ChroPath, which tells you the Xpath or CssSelector that you can use to position. It keeps saying: No such element...I'm quite confused. I'm not even trying to automatically log in or anything.

here are the codes:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='E:/data mining/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=823730524426477568')
ele = driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0').text
print(ele)
```

Error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"} 
> (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)

It's so strange, because everything is right on the first page, and I don't even need to scroll down to see the information, but it won't be scraped...

Comment: Please post a more accurate sample of you code. There is an error in what you posted that would cause a separate exception than what you provided, and the exception that you did provide is not relevant to the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue with your code, try this:

```py
ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.css-901oao.css-16my406.r-poiln3.r-bcqeeo.r-qvutc0').text
```

However, because of how the site is formatted, it won't get you the result you want. It appears that not only do they rotate the class name, but there isn't enough variability in how the elements are labelled to make anything but XPath a viable option for getting specific data. (Unless you want to go through a list of all the elements with the same class to find what you need). After some initial site interactions, these XPaths worked for me:

```py
following = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span[1]/span').text
followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/a/span[1]/span').text
```

Comment: Thank you. XPath seems to be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, there are over 100 elements with classes 'css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0' on that page.

To avoid absolute xpath you could use something like this for e.g. number of followers:

Find `span` with descendant span with text 'Followers'. Above that, on same level (sibling) there is `span` with child - number of followers for text

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[descendant::span[text()='Followers']]/preceding-sibling::span/span").text
```

Comment: I later discovered that too. Your plan seems quite feasible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The selectors which you are using are very much fragile. chropath gives fragile xpath which is changing in next run so script is failing. You might like to use relative xpath generated by selectorshub which is much robust.

[image]